# How to check every item in list is false when it is not a boolean list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there a way to check every item in list whether it is true or false. Because if creating a List I would need to insert the field I wanted to check one by one. Which will affect the efficiency when running. Since  `genreList` is a lot of item.
Function

```
public void CheckFalse(List<program> programList, List<genreList> genreList)
{
    foreach (var programListItem in programList)
    {
        
        if (genreList.Where(x => x.ProgramId  == programListItem.Id).Count(x => true) != 0)
        {
            //RUN TASK
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class program
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int channel { get; set; }
}
public class genreList
{
public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public bool Math { get; set; }
public bool Science { get; set; }
public bool Programming { get; set; }
//Many more genre List but I will only list a few
}
```

Comment: Any updates on the below answer. was it helpful? did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0),

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
> condition.

```
public void CheckFalse(List<program> programList, List<genreList> genreList)
{
    foreach (var programListItem in programList)
    {   
        if (genreList.Any(x => x.ProgramId  == programListItem.Id))
        {
            //RUN TASK
        }
    }
}
```